# Magento 2.4 CSP Module - how do I whitelist base 64 encoded fonts?

Tags: magento2, content-security-policy

In Magento 2.4 with the Magento_CSP module enabled in report only mode, on every page load I am seeing 2 entries like

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings observed the loading of a resource at data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAE… (“font-src”). A CSP report is being sent.
```

Which looks like fonts loaded from base 64 encoded data instead of a URL. I'm not sure where it is coming from. Maybe some 3rd party js, GTM, etc.
How do I whitelist this, or ignore it and prevent it from showing up several times in the console for every page load??

Comment: You just need to add `data:` source to the `font-src` directive of your CSP in the Magento_CSP module.

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: Only you have a code example. Please show me CSP rules you set in Magento_CSP and I show you how to modify it to allow `data;` in the `font-src`

Comment: No, I don't have a code example. The rules are setup based on the Magento dev docs, which do not contain a code example for this situation...

Comment: You have Magento_CSP module enabled. This module is published some CSP. You need to add the `font-src data:` directive to it, or if there is already a `font-src` directive, to add the` data: `schema to its rules. I can't see what policy you have published, only you can see it.